# Update Spring beans in a Grails application without restarting Tomcat

Tags: spring, grails

We have a Grails 2.0 application with an external applicationConfig.groovy and an action on a controller we can use to read the config in and update the application's config.groovy settings without restarting the application.
We use `grailsApplication.config.merge(new ConfigSlurper(Environment.current.name).parse(new File(configFilename).text))` to accomplish this.

We want to be able to also update our spring beans in resources.groovy in the same manner.  We can create resources.xml in the application's spring directory which would be plain text on the server.  We can modify the file on the server but it is not automatically read in, requiring a Tomcat restart.  We also have security concerns about having our beans in plain text where someone using the application may be able to view in a browser.

We have put an applicationResources.groovy file in the same external directory as the applicationConfig.groovy and access it in resources.groovy using `importBeans('file:/pathToConfig/applicationResources.groovy')` which we have verified works on application startup.  We can not find if there is a way to have the application read in the changes to the applicationResources.groovy file without restarting Tomcat, does anyone have any suggestions?

You can put Spring beans in config.groovy but our beans that work fine in resource.groovy do not work in config.groovy.

```
beans {
    DirContextValidator(org.springframework.ldap.pool.validation.DefaultDirContextValidator){}
}
```

results in the error `ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Entry in bean config for bean 'DirContextValidator' must be a Map`